# (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components in dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2

This is my Fragment dagger2 component:

```
@PreMainFrag
@Component(modules = {MainFragModule.class},
        dependencies = AppComponent.class)
public interface MainFragComponent {
        void inject(MainFragment mainFragment);
}
```

and this is MainFragModule:

```
@Module
public class MainFragModule {

    MainFragment mainFragment;

    public MainFragModule(MainFragment mainFragment) {
        this.mainFragment = mainFragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @PreMainFrag
    MainFragment getMainFragment(){
        return mainFragment;
    }

}
```

But when I want to make dagger I got this error:

```
symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent
  location: package com.t.stm.application.di
E:\Projects\Android\Stm\Stm\stm\src\main\java\com\t\stm\mainFragment\main\di\MainFragComponent.java:9: error: com.t.stm.mainFragment.main.di.MainFragComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components:
@Component(modules = {MainFragModule.class},
^
      @com.t.stm.application.di.AppScope com.t.stm.application.di.AppComponent
2 errors
:stm:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

What is going on? I added `@PreMainFrag` on my component !!

This is my scope class:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PreMainFrag {
}
```

************************** EDIT *******************************

This is AppComponent :

```
@AppScope
@Component(modules = {NetworkModule.class,
        AppRetroServiceModule.class,
        MainRepositoryModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    Gson getGson();

    APIService getService();

    @AppQualifierHttpClientThread
    APIService getServiceWithThread();

    MainRepository getMainRepository();

}
```

and it's app scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface AppScope {
}
```

I also changed `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)` to `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` but nothing is changed.

When i removed `dependencies = AppComponent.class` from `MainFragComponent` everything is ok and i can make dagger but what is dependency problem?

Comment: please post your appComponent class and appScope class aswell

Comment: I have updated dude @seyedJafari

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue.
perhaps verify your modules